# How to write a list into a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

Hi, I am trying to write a list with the key, "score" to a CSV file. Ultimately, I would like to store the scores along three other attributes (initials, gender and class) and be able to display it as a Dataframe.

```
print("Game over! Your score was: ", score)
leaderboard_dict[score] = [current_player_initials, current_player_gender, real_player_class]
print(leaderboard_dict)
with open('leaderboard_doc.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, leaderboard_dict.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(leaderboard_dict)
pd.read_csv(path)
```

This is my current code, but when I run it, I get an error saying, "Error Tokenizing: Expected 1 field in line 12, got 2"

Does anyone know a solution to this? I have been stuck in my code for a while trying to figure this one out. It is almost as if it is not recognizing the formatting when going into the CSV file.

Comment: I would like the CSV to list the score in one column, initials in the next, then gender, then class, but instead it is writing the score in the column and [initals, gender, class] beneath it.

Comment: Whoops, misread that. Regardless, what's your input?

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('leaderboard_doc.csv', 'w')
f.write("score,initials,gender,class")
for score in leaderboard_dict:
    initials,gender,class = leaderboard_dict[score]
    f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s" % (score,initials,gender,class))
f.close()
```

Note, however, that your dictionary itself is a bit flawed in that you only allow a single instance of every score. I'm not sure what exactly the rest of the context is, but I would recommend having the keys be something that are guaranteed to be unique, e.g. initials in this case